Android Thread InputStream from web page
I have an old app in Android that just downloads the content of a web page and sends it to a Bluetooth printer. It was working fine but with the new Google restrictions to Android apps it's just impossible to install it in the new Android 14.
I already changed the targetSkd to 32 but it requires other changes. One of which is that apparently I can't open an inputStream from the main activity. I read something about asyncTasks but apparently they were discontinued too.
This is what the code looks like:
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_printdoc) {
        printdoc();
    }
  //...
}

public void printdoc(){
    try{
        connectToPrinter();

    }   catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        //BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new URL(uriToPrint).openConnection().getInputStream()));
        URL myUrl = new URL(uriToPrint);
        HttpURLConnection myCon = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = null;
        try {
            stream = myCon.getInputStream();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);

        byte[] init = {0x1b,0x74,0x03};
        woosim.controlCommand(init, init.length);
        
        //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while( ( line = bufferedReader.readLine() ) != null) {
            String noHTMLString = ConverCore(line);
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("data=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if (matcher.find()){
                woosim.saveSpool(UTF_8, noHTMLString + "\n", 0x11, false);
                //Toast.makeText(this, Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                pattern = Pattern.compile("data-src=\"(.*?)\"");
                matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if(matcher.find()){
                    try {
                        downloadFile(matcher.group(1), Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + "/sig.bmp");
                        int resp = this.PrintImage(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/sig.bmp", 0, 0, 0);
                    }catch(Exception ex) {
                    }
                }else {
                    woosim.saveSpool(UTF_8, noHTMLString + "\n", 0, false);
                }
            }
        }
        
        bufferedReader.close();

        byte[] ff ={0x0c};
        woosim.controlCommand(ff, 1);
        woosim.printSpool(true);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Impressão concluida.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

How can I do this with a Thread or Executor or any other async kind of task in API32 or later?
